# Retain jQuery functionality when buttons are added on the go

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a block of list element which I need to add when "Add" button is clicked.
HTML:

```
<li>
    <div><h3 >User name sss updated this.
        <input type="button" value="X" class="delete"/></br></h3>
    </div>

        SOME TEXT HERE          
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("li").slideUp();
});

$("#addPost").click(function(){
    var inData = '<li><div><h3>User name sss updated this.<input type="button" value="X" class="delete"></input></br></h3></div>';
    $("#midContent ul").append(inData+'Sarthak</li>');
});
```

This block has a delete button and a jQuery function attached to it.

If the block already exist on the page, its working fine.
But, when I add this block using jQuery append, the block is rendered rightly, but delete functionality does not work on newly added block.
Where I am going wrong?

Also, what will be the better way to add this block than hardcoding in JS code? (just by referring the element already on page by using id or class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate events for dynamically created DOM nodes. You can delegate to the parent div, or the document itself.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(e) { 
    //your code here
});
```

The second argument in the click handler is the selector for which you are attaching the click handler.

Further reading: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the event `.on('click',function(){})` on dynamically created elements.

```
$(".delete").on('click',function(){
    $(this).closest("li").slideUp();
});

$("#addPost").on('click',function(){
    var inData = '<li><div><h3>User name sss updated this.<input type="button" value="X" class="delete"></input></br></h3></div>';
    $("#midContent ul").append(inData+'Sarthak</li>');
});
```

Also, why create a variable when you could append the code directly?

Comment: you need to go "one up" from the dynamic events, $(".delete").on will only find ones existing at call-time.

Comment: actually I was trying few different things, so I created that variable.